# TFS: Check In throws Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, checkin

I can get Latest Version from TFS, but I cannot check in my changes. Visual Studio 2012 throws below error

> One or more of the pending changes no longer exists or was modified.
>   The list of pending changes has been refreshed and is now current.
>   Please inspect the list of pending changes and try your operation
>   again.

Tried the below,

1. Back up the project and Undo the pending changes, and again merged
   the changes and tried check in, not working.
2. Deleted the project folder manually and Open the solution from source and again tried check in, not working.

Till yesterday evening Check In was worked fine for me, but today it's not working.

But still Check In working for one of my colleague.

Comment: As the error said, can you see the pending changes in the Source Control? Did you have any other workspace holding the pending changes?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, Yes i can see. You're right I noticed 2 unwanted folders in DefaultCollection, I just undo those pending changes. Now CheckIn working fine:) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 projects in my workspace which are not in TFS server. I just did Undo Pending Changes of those two projects. Now Check In working fine :)

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue but I couldn't spot anything that shouldn't be there but I did have a load of excluded changes across a number of projects (mostly just opening up old projects or incorrectly marked changes when nothing has changed). Once I clearly a couple of these it was back to working to guessing it forced TF to get past whatever it was being held up on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can not access to Source-Explorer and i get error with this message: Team foundation services are not available from serve xxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxxx .